# for() and random() FUNCTIONS

Tags: c

Why is this code not working properly?

The intent of this code is to generate and print two random numbers separately
as many times as user choose.

M.T.
Thanks.

```
  #include <stdio.h>  
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <time.h>
  #define random(x) rand() % x
  #define randomize srand((unsigned)time(NULL))

  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  int x=0;
  int y=0;

  int main(void) 
  {     
    printf("insert number of loops:");
    scanf("%d",x);
    for(y=0;y=x;y++)
    {
      randomize;
      i = random(51);
      j = random(51);
      printf("%d\n",i);
      printf("%d\n",j);
     }
   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: See https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful to learn more on the generation of random number.  `time(NULL)` only change once per second. Since `srand()` is called multiple times using `time(NULL)` as a seed, the generated numbers change only once per second or so. Notice that if RAND_MAX is not such that RAND_MAX%51==50, the numbers are not generated with exactly the same probability.

Comment: Notice that [random(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random.3.html) is a [POSIX function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/random.html) so you'll better use another name for your macro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `srand` more than once. Place `randomize;` outside the `for` loop. Another problem is with the statement

```
scanf("%d",x);
```

you forget to place `&` before `x`.

Also You need to correct the loop condition `y = x` to `y < x` as mentioned in comment by @Cool Guy.

Comment: Also mention the mistake here: `for(y=0;y=x;y++)`.

Comment: hi! where is the mistake? it could be there beacause the program start an infinite generation of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

solved, thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define random(x) rand() % x
#define randomize srand((unsigned)time(NULL))

int i=0;
int j=0;
int x=0;
int y=0;

int main(void) 
{     
printf("insert number of loops:");
scanf("%d",&x);
randomize;
for(y=0;y<x;y++)
{
i = random(51);
j = random(51);
printf("%d\n",i);
printf("%d\n",j);
}
return 0;
}
```